# How to get canvas Image coordinates relative to zoom with easelJS?

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I have an image inside of a canvas and I want to get mouse position coordinates when I click on the image. Asking for `stage.clientX` and `stage.clientY` works when image is not zoomed, but after zoom they retrieve stage coordinates instead of (zoomed)image coordinates.

How can I get them?

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/createjs-discussion/_n3yDDlqkKg/WuhSGEaZ1rgJ:

On mouse click, perform `stage.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)`

Ref: http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_globalToLocal